# Several iPhone Core Plot Questions

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-plot

I am new to core plot and am working on a project where it seems to be a good fit.  I have some questions, mostly on the capabilities of core plot:

1) I am displaying a scatter plot and want to put a horizontal line on the graph and changed the color of the plot line and gradient when the data crosses this line.  Can the framework do this? If so, can someone point me in the right direction and if not, can someone give me a hint on how to best plug into core plot to make this happen?

2) I want the y axis to be fixed but allow the user to scale the x axis only by pinching.  I am able to get close to the desired behavior by using GlobalXRange and GlobalYRange but once you zoom out, you cannot zoom the x axis back in.  Any hints on how to fix that?

3) I want to add annotations at key events.  What delegate call do I use for that.

4) I want to be able to display a static vertical line and allow the user to scroll the graph.  I then want to display the exact data under the vertical line (which does not move as the graph scrolls).  Any hint on how to do that?

Any help/answer you can provide will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This is Q-A service fro specific programming problems not general concepts. Split your question into single questions so others can answer them.

Comment: If you've got four questions, then you should ask four questions, not join them into one question. Please edit this question to only include item 1, and ask the others individually.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your first question, you should use CoreGraphics. Google tutorials on CoreGraphics + Gradients, you can also include CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents on your google search to get better results.